# Scrapy won't let me login to asp.net page (ASPX)

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

Hi I'm having trouble getting my scrapy spider script to login to a aspx (asp.net) website

The script is supposed to crawl a website for product information (it's a suppliers website so we are allowed to do this) but for whatever reason the script is not able to login to the webpage using the script below, there is a username and password field along with a image button but when the script runs it simply doesn't work and we are redirected to the main page... I believe it has something to do with the page being asp.net and apparently i need to pass more information but i've honestly tried everything and im at a loss of what to do next!

What am I doing wrong?

```
import scrapy

class LeedaB2BSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'leedab2b'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.leedab2b.co.uk/customerlogin.aspx'
        ]


    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response=response,   
                                                formdata={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbUsername': 'emailaddress@gmail.com', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbPassword': 'yourpassword'},
                                                clickdata={'id': 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbcustomerloginbutton'},
                                                callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        self.logger.info("you are at %s" % response.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormRequest.from_response` doesn't seem to send __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT in formdata, try to add them manually:

```
formdata={
    '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbcustomerloginbutton',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbUsername': 'emailaddress@gmail.com',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbPassword': 'yourpassword'
}
```